# css custom rule not detecting issue in code, sonarqube

Tags: css, sonarqube, rules

I've created a custome rule for css which should detect if class name has number in it then mark it as error but nothing happening. I've used following regular expressions for it:

```
[.]?[0-9]/g
```

[Image 1 which show how I created new custom rule from UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAZvj.png)

[Image 2 which show how I created new custom rule from UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH3Yv.png)

Comment: @AlFonce where I've to write that code? I didn't wrote any code for it. I just added this rule from UI as show in images I attached.

Answer (score 1):

From the provided screenshots, it looks like you created a rule from one of the rule templates: either Regular expression on property or Regular expression on comment. A class selector is neither a property nor a comment. That's why it doesn't work.

To fulfill your needs, you can activate the css:selector-naming-convention - Selectors should follow a naming convention rule and update the regular expression parameter. Note that this rule will apply to both class and id selectors.

If you only want to enforce this rule for class selectors, you will have to write a custom rule. See https://github.com/racodond/sonar-css-custom-rules-plugin for more details.